# Adding logout timer to spring security application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I created one of the spring application project (a simple login form). where I recently added "logout" functionality. I was wondering how to add a logout timer so the user will be logged out fo inactivity after a certain interval of time. I tried looking resource on stack overflow as well as spring documentation but couldn't find one. Please note that I am using **ALL JAVA CONFIGURATION** (**NO XML** bsaed configuration).

So far I have designed a simple login functionality, which works as desired but I am trying refactor the "logout functionality" so user won't have to click on logout functionality all the time. I am attaching link for my codebase, please review it.

project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K1yhxsrUWxJe6iaeEL_Pj2HJ9C41vYaT/view?usp=share_link

*Note
while importing my project from DRIVE, you will have to add tomcat server (v9.0) and add the path of the server in the project as well.

Comment: Look for session management, you will find a ton of information

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.